# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'zipfile' when using pip

Tags: python, module, pip

I'm new to Python and I have installed multiple versions (Anaconda3 and Python 3.7.4) on my Mac.

My `pip` is not working.  When I run any `pip` command, everything appears to be importing properly. But it gets the last line, `import zipfile`, and I get the message:

```py
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'zipfile'
```

I have been Googling for hours and I can't seem to find a solution.

My Python now lives in the Anaconda directory `/users/NAME/opt/anaconda3/`.

Ultimately, I would like to start from scratch and just reinstall Python 3.7.4 again, so it's all nice and clean. I can't uninstall Anaconda because I get the same `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'zipfile'`.

I have also tried to install the module `zipfile` and that doesn't work either.

Can someone help?

Thanks

Thanks everyone for your help so far.  I am really new to Python, so I don't think I explained myself properly.

UPDATE: I think I have fixed my problem.  Pip was looking for the file zipfile, so I downloaded https://pypi.org/project/zipfile36/#files and changed the name of zipfile36.py to zipfile.py.

Seems like it did the trick.

Comment: Can you please help me with this: run `which pip` in your bash and let me know the response!

Comment: Seems to me like you need to reinstall Python, since _zipfile_ is part of it's standard library, it should always be available and importable. Installing a _zipfile_ replacement from _PyPI_ is unlikely to be what you want.

Comment: I would like to reinstall Python, but I don't know how to. Since I have both Anaconda and Python, I would actually like to uninstall everything, and reinstall a fresh version of Python.  I tried anaconda-clean and I was prompted to delete .conda, etc but the Anaconda Folder is still in my usr/opt/ folder.  Python -- version still says 3.7.4.